# Access properties / values set in the bean in camel route

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

Is there a way to access some values or properties that are set in the bean which can be accessed in the camel route ?
Example,

```
from(RoutA.getEndpoint()).routeId(RouteA.getEndpoint())
        .to(RouteB.getEndpoint())
        .to(RouteC.getEndpoint())
        .to(RouteD.getEndpoint())
        ;
```

I am setting a flag in routeA bean and based on the flag I need to call some routes vs others

```
from(RouteA.getEndpoint()).routeId(RouteA.getEndpoint())
        .choice()
            .when(header(flag).isEqualTo(true)).to(RouteB.getEndpoint())
        .end()
        .to(RouteC.getEndpoint())
        .to(RouteD.getEndpoint())
        ;
```

How to add the flag as a header or any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your processor and set it call before your `when` part. E.g.

```
from(RouteA.getEndpoint()).routeId(RouteA.getEndpoint())
        .process(yourProcessor) 
        .choice()
            .when(header(flag).isEqualTo(true)).to(RouteB.getEndpoint())
        .end()
        .to(RouteC.getEndpoint())
        .to(RouteD.getEndpoint());
```

And in `yourProcessor` impl write

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {       
    ...
    Map<String, Object> headers = exchange.getIn().getHeaders(); 
    headers.put("flag", Boolean.TRUE);    

    exchange.getOut().setHeaders(headers);        
    ...
}
```

Comment: I need to set the flag in the RouteA's bean. But I don't have access to the exchange in the bean

Comment: @kushan85 can you share here your `RouteA` API?